# has anyone tried putting a cell in jupyter 7 that can handle streaming data?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pyzmq, data-stream

**Please note I am asking if this CAN be done NOT how to do it.**

I am about to try jupyter 7 and I think it should be able to handle streaming data which updates a cell. So I would set up a stream of price from a data source which updates a datastructure in the cell once every second. There might be 20 symbols in the data structure.  The feed would come in as a structured ZMQ message which would be parsed and used to update the change inside the cell. So the structure might look like this

```
symbol     price
AAPL       100
DE         232
TSLA       1000
```

a new ZMQ ipm would come in reflecting a change in DE's price

```
DE 250
```

the cell structure would then look like this ( auto refresh )

```
symbol     price
AAPL       100
DE         250
TSLA       1000
```

My understanding is the jupyter uses ZMQ under the hood and jupyter 7 has a collaboration mode that might help me here.

Comment: Not sure about versions but I've seen that ipywidgets can be refreshed dynamically as of 7+ years ago when I last looked

Comment: Maybe this helps - https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html#interacting-with-output-widgets-from-background-threads

Comment: This might make a better fit at [the Jupyter Community discourse forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/) since it is 'If this can be done' question. If you do put it there make sure you link in both places so others following in your footsteps can follow along.

Comment: @OneCricketeer thank you so much. I didn't know about this functionality

Comment: @Wayne  I don't use discourse as I refuse to give them my phone number.  Thanks for the suggestion though. I'll see what other forums exist.

Comment: You can login there with Google or Github. You shouldn't need a phone number

Comment: Hi there @OneCricketeer  tried it a while back and they wanted a phone number at some point.   I don't trust that site to be honest, just a gut reaction. I prefer discord. Thanks for the reply though